# Chrome extension reusing page's script

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a page that binds an event with jQuery:

```
$('#element').click(function() { /* do something */ });
```

I already wrote an extension to access and modify the DOM in a page. I create the element #newelement. I need now attach the same event mentioned above to the #newelement, however I need to reuse the code embedded in the page. I cannot just copy the javascript and put inside the extension code, because this will be a mess.

This can be done? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can bind the event to multiple elements:

```
$('#element, #newelemnt').on('click', function() { /* do something */ });
```

Comment: Hiya bruv, I recon the element is added dynamically `:)` might want to use `.on` innit :P **or** its not clear man, I might be wrong, anyhoo will wait for OP +1 anyways

Comment: @Tats_innit Hiya buv, i wasn't sure the new element is added dynamically or is hard-coded, thanks man `:)`

Comment: `:)` I know well benefit of doubt ++1 to you!

Answer (score 1):

the Api you are looking for is called `.on` : http://api.jquery.com/on/

So now when you add a new element you the `.on` event will bind the element.

**for OP**

you can do combine elements in case the element is not dynamically added:

Good discussion: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-combining-selectors

like this:

```
$('#ele_id, #ele_idfoo, #ele_new_id').click(function() { /* do something shared here*/ });
```